# How to show that the $\max(P(A),P(B)) \leq P(A\cup B)$

Tags: probability

> Given $A ,B$ events, how do I show that $\max(P(A),P(B))\le P(A\cup B)$?

I understand this intuitively, just not how to show it mathematically.

Comment: Use `$\max(P(A),P(B)) \leq  P(A\cup B)$` to show $\max(P(A),P(B)) \leq  P(A\cup B)$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $X \subseteq Y$ implies $P(X) \le P((Y)$.

Now $A \subseteq A \cup B$ and $B \subseteq A \cup B$ imply $P(A) \le P(A \cup B)$ and $P(B) \le P(A \cup B)$, i.e. $\max \{P(A), P(B) \} \le P(A \cup B)$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $A\cup B = A\sqcup(B\backslash A)$, so $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B\backslash A) \ge P(A)$. Similarly $P(A\cup B) \ge P(B)$. Combining, $\max\{P(A), P(B)\} \le P(A\cup B)$.